# Error trying to convert .avi to .iso in DeVeDe - Conversion failed. It seems a bug of Mencoder

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion

After a lot of Googling, I still cannot convert an avi to an iso.

I tried to install ffmpeg from ppa https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg and I changed in preferences "Encoder for movies and Encoder for Menus".

I reinstalled several times the devede, and nothing works.

Can someone me help ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. Why do you need to convert your avi?

Answer (score 0):

AVI and ISO are formats for completely different things. Think of an ISO more like a ZIP file. An AVI is a video file.

You can put an AVI in to an ISO but you can't convert it because they are completely different things.